# Query to display student_no, prj_name and prj_dur

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following table

```
        TBL_STUDENT (STUDENT_NO VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR2 (10) STUDENT_DOB DATE STUDENT_DOJ DATE)

        TBL_PROJECT (PRJ_NO VARCHAR2 (3) PRIMARY KEY PRJ_NAME VARCHAR2 (15) PRJ_DUR NUMBER (2) PRJ_PLATFORM VARCHAR2 (10))

       TBL_STUDENTPROJECT (STUDENT_NO VARCHAR2 (3) PRJ_NO VARCHAR2 (3) DESIGNATION VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARYKEY (STUDENT_NO,PRJ_NO,DESIGNATION) FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT_NO) of TBL_STUDENT FOREIGN KEY(PRJ_NO) of TBL_PROJECT)
```

I want to display student_no, prj_name and prj_dur;

```
        select p.prj_name, s.student_no, p.prj_dur from tbl_project p inner join on tbl_studentproject s where p.prj_no = s.prj_no
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to do **Inner join** to find prj_name, student_no and prj_dur.

```
SELECT p.PRJ_NAME, s.STUDENT_NO, p.PRJ_DUR 
     from TBL_STUDENTPROJECT sp 
     INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT s on sp.STUDENT_NO = s.STUDENT_NO 
     INNER JOIN TBL_PROJECT p ON sp.PRJ_NO = p.PRJ_NO;
```

Comment: This will return all the students who are working on at least one project. What if the OP wants to know the students with no project return in the same query? You're answer is good but limited. I vote up since the OP didn't add that information.

Comment: Of-course to use LEFT JOIN if requires all student irrespective of project. Since it was not mention in question i did not use left-join.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have all the project and project duration of each student then use [left join.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

```
SELECT p.PRJ_NAME, s.STUDENT_NO, p.PRJ_DUR 
FROM TBL_STUDENT s  
LEFT JOIN TBL_STUDENTPROJECT sp on sp.STUDENT_NO=s.STUDENT_NO 
LEFT JOIN TBL_PROJECT p ON sp.PRJ_NO=p.PRJ_NO;
```